# More than one build in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to put together a Makefile to compile a number of documents.

There a three separate 'jobs' in my Makefile, my problem is that only the first job is processed. Each of the jobs works by themselves, or if they are the first job in the file.

It is important that running the total build is as easy as `make`, so the people contributing with documents don't have to fiddle around with things.

How do I make all three jobs run?

```
# Generate index
index.html: index.md
    pandoc \
        index.md \
        -f markdown_github \
        -t html5 \
        -s \
        -o index.html


# Generate background-writing documents
source := background-writing
output := dist
sources := $(wildcard $(source)/*.md)
objects := $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(subst $(source),$(output),$(sources)))
all: $(objects)

$(output)/%.pdf: $(source)/%.md
    pandoc \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --number-sections \
        -f markdown  $< \
        -s \
        -o $@


# Compile report
source := draft
output := dist
sources := $(wildcard $(source)/*.md)
all: $(output)/report-print.pdf

$(output)/report-print.pdf: $(sources)
    cat $^ | pandoc \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --number-sections \
        --toc \
        --from markdown \
        -s \
        -o $@


.PHONY : clean

clean:
    rm -f $(output)/*.pdf
```

-- UPDATE

Based on the answers below, the fully functioning Makefile looks like this:

```
all: index.html docs report

# Generate index
index.html: index.md
    pandoc \
        index.md \
        -f markdown_github \
        -t html5 \
        -s \
        -o index.html


output := dist


# Generate background-writing documents
docsource := background-writing
docsources := $(wildcard $(docsource)/*.md)
objects := $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(subst $(docsource),$(output),$(docsources)))
docs: $(objects)

$(output)/%.pdf: $(docsource)/%.md
    pandoc \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --number-sections \
        -f markdown  $< \
        -s \
        -o $@


# Compile report
reportsource := draft
reportsources := $(wildcard $(reportsource)/*.md)
report: $(output)/report-print.pdf

$(output)/report-print.pdf: $(reportsources)
    cat $^ | pandoc \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --number-sections \
        --toc \
        --from markdown \
        -s \
        -o $@


.PHONY : clean all docs report

clean:
    rm -f $(output)/*.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specify a target, only the first target in the file will be built. Conventionally you would have a target `all` as the first target with all other targets as dependencies.  That way all targets will be built by default.  So in general the first target should be:

```
all : job1 job2 job3
```

I suggest that in your case, the two `all` targets should be renamed. The duplicate macros `source`, `output` and `sources` also need to be unique or the duplication removed.

Comment: This is generally right, but there are a number of issues.  First and most critically, you NEVER use commas between prerequisites; this will give you an error (failure to build target `index.html,` for example).  It should be `all: index.html docs report`.  Second, it's fine if you have multiple targets, like `all`, in the makefile with different prerequisites; as long as only _one_ of them has a recipe (in this case, `all` doesn't have any recipe at all so it's fine).  Third, because `all`, `docs`, and `report` are not real targets the author should declare them as `.PHONY`.

Comment: Lastly, you should make clear why the author's attempt failed: the default behavior of make, if you don't give any targets on the command line, is to make sure the _first_ target it finds in the makefile is up to date.  In the question the first target was `index.html`, so that's what make would build unless you asked for a different one with `make report` etc.  So, the answer is to create a target like `all`, which depends on all the things you want built by default, and make sure _that_ is the first target in the makefile.  Then `make` and `make all` are equivalent.

Comment: I worked your suggestions into the Makefile, and it is now working. I included the functioning file in the question so others might learn from it too. Thanks guys.

Comment: @MadScientist : Thanks, improved in line with your comments.

Comment: You shouldn't declare `index.html` as phony.  That's an actual target file that is created.  It should be `all` that's declared phony, and you declare it by making it prerequisite of  `.PHONY`.  Two different lines; first `.PHONY: all report docs` and then afterwards (or before, whatever) `all: index.html docs report`

Comment: @MadScientist : It may have been simpler had you just edited the corrections in. It's largely irrelevant in any case, so I have removed the detail.

Comment: Perhaps; I don't like to edit other peoples' answers in general.

Comment: @MadScientist : It is sometimes a hard call, whether to modify someoneelses work, but in this case it would not have materially affected the answer to correct by makefile syntax.  I cannot think of the last time I created a makefile by hand, so I was not on totally solid ground.